# R Formatting uneven dates

Tags: r, date

I have a .csv data set that has the following date format:

```
01/10/2013
```

however there are events that have this format:

```
13-14/10/2013
```

Does anyone know how can I format this in order to have something in "%d/%m/%Y"?

Comment: For situations like `13-14/10/2013` what is your expected outcome? Is it sufficient for that to be cut to `13/10/2013` or `14/10/2013` or would you like to be able to somehow retain both those dates?

Comment: I wanted both options (if they were possible) since I'm still not sure which one would be more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain both dates, *i.e.* `13-14/10/2013` becomes `c("13/10/2013", "14/10/2013")`, you can use `tidyr` and `dplyr` to separate the dates, then the days, then combine everything back together:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(dates  = c("12/10/2013", "13-14/10/2013"), 
                  values = c(4,6))

df1 %>% 
  separate(dates, into = c("d", "m", "y"), sep = "/") %>% 
  separate_rows(d, sep = "-") %>% 
  mutate(dates = paste(d, m, y, sep = "/")) %>% 
  select(dates, values)

       dates values
1 12/10/2013      4
2 13/10/2013      6
3 14/10/2013      6
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you want to have October, 14th out of this you need

```
gsub("[[:digit:]]{1,2}-", "", "13-14/10/2013")
```

If you want October, 13th you need

```
gsub("-[[:digit:]]{1,2}", "", "13-14/10/2013")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is like this:

```
d <- c("01/10/2013", "10/01/2015", "13-14/10/2013")
```

Then you can capture the bad pattern with regular expressions, and then call `gsub()` on the entire vector to replace leading `xx-yy`s with either the first day (`xx`):

```
gsub("^(\\d{2})\\-(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "\\1/\\3/\\4", d)
```

or the second day (`yy`):

```
gsub("^(\\d{2})\\-(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "\\2/\\3/\\4", d)
```

depending on which is appropriate in your situation.